# Access Ubuntu PC behind NAT router by software service

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, nat, portforwarding

How to access Ubuntu PC behind NAT router without reconfiguring NAT router, but by pure software (apps or services)?

Here is the problem description:

1. In my office I have Ubuntu PC which has VNC enabled. Ubuntu PC has private IP address and is behind not just one but two Internet routers, so configuring NAT on them is not possible (I do not have access to them).
2. At my home, I have my own LAN workgroup and one server PC (windows xp) which is directly connected to Internet and has public ip address.

So what I want is a way to access VNC server on my Ubuntu PC directly from PC which is on LAN at my home. As you can see both computers have private IP addresses and both are behind NAT routers. I would need something like LogMeIn except not for Windows but for Ubuntu.

Also I thought maybe to write program in C++ or Java which should consist of servers and clients which could do port forwarding and I have some ideas but I would really like to see if there is already a way to do it in Ubuntu without reinventing a wheel.

Comment: Did you ever come up with that C++ solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [TeamViewer for Linux](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx). According to the [FAQ](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/9-Does-it-work-behind-firewalls-proxy-server-and-NAT-routers.aspx) it supports this.

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed. I tested from my home and I can connect to my Ubuntu PC at office with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You could establish an SSH tunnel between the two computers.

Here's several ways [How to Tunnel VNC over SSH.](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/tunnel-vnc-over-ss)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu's (or any other Linux) built-in tools (ssh, x11vnc, tigervnc). Works through any combination of NATs. The repository contains a script for a user-friendly connection of all these tools.

https://github.com/skosachiov/linux-remote-assistance

Сonvenient to use in a corporate environment, as Ansible is used for deployment.